# Como hacer para que el glyphicon de check o error solo aparezca cuando haga submit con el plugin formvalidation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bueno, como verán la forma en que normalmente funciona el formvalidation, es colocando un glyphicon como correcto o incorrecto **mientras escribes** el correo o contraseña con su expresión regular, como en este ejemplo que aparece en la documentación [Ejemplo](http://formvalidation.io/validators/emailAddress/), y me gustaría saber como hacer que se **despliegue el glyphicon cuando termine de escribir** en el input, **o cuando de click en submit**.

No he encontrado la forma de hacerlo, he querido usar el metodo de **delay** 
[como dice esta parte de la documentación](http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/), pero no me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándome en este ejemplo de la documentación: [Enabling validators](http://formvalidation.io/examples/enable-validator/), asumo que es lo que deseas, aunque lo único es que tienes que desactivar/activar la validación en cada campo y esto puede ser largo si tienes muchos en tu formulario:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#enableForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                full_name: {
                    enabled: false,
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    enabled: false,
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The password is required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    enabled: false,
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The confirm password is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        identical: {
                            field: 'password',
                            message: 'The password and its confirm must be the same'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('click', '[type=submit]', function() {
            $('#enableForm')
                    .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'full_name')
                    .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'password')
                    .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'confirm_password');
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">
<div class="container">
<form id="enableForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name (*)</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">New password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Confirm password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, es que no me habia quedado claro como hacer lo del enableFieldValidators, pero ahora si.